How indicate to robots, website in the three languages?
I'm making infotainment platform on three languages (ru, en, he) with targeting on the Israeli market (multilingual people). Perhaps in the future - a social network. How indicate to robots (like Google), website in the three languages?
The main problem: Robots don't tell you language they are requesting page in. My application written on Java, and for get a page in one of 3 (ru, en, he), before HTML, I am doing request getLocale().getISO3Language(); But robots ignore this parameter, and by default all pages only on English. On the page "feed" can be messages on three languages, and I don't want to promotion some a one. How indicate to robots, website in the three languages?

You can indicate to search engines that your website supports multiple languages, with hreflang attribute in your HTML. This attribute tells search engines about the different language versions of a page, which helps them serve the correct language version to users based on their preferences.
In your case you can use hreflang like this:
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.yoursite.com/en/page" hreflang="en" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.yoursite.com/ru/page" hreflang="ru" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.yoursite.com/he/page" hreflang="he" />

Also, keep in mind that each language version of your page has a canonical tag pointing to itself to prevent duplicate content issues.

So, it should look like this: <link rel="canonical" rel="alternate" href="https://www.yoursite.com/en/page" hreflang="he"/> ?

@HimselfProducer No, this <link> tag is incorrect because it combines rel="canonical" and rel="alternate" in a single tag, which is not valid HTML syntax. Here is the correct one <link rel="canonical" href="https://www.yoursite.com/en/page" />

One of the three languages must be set as default. Two others must be recorded with rel="alternate" So, on the page must be three entries: Two with rel="alternate" and one canonical? Or how? - I don't understand...

@HimselfProducer your head code will look like this: `




` where each page will have all three language tags but only one canonical tag for the page itself.
But this means, all pages are canonical... OK. Let's see what comes of this :)

@HimselfProducer You're correct that each page will have its own canonical tag, making it the canonical version of that specific language. However, the use of alternate tags helps search engines understand the different language versions available for the same content.
